# Colored frame in includegraphics environment

Tags: graphics, color, framed

I like using `\includegraphics[<your options>,frame]{image}`
to create a tight border around my images. How can I change the color of the border?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[frame]{example-image-A}  
\end{document}
```

[image: Example image with small tight border]

Comment: The standard `\includegraphics` command does not have a frame option, if you have a package that is adding that key, perhaps it adds color as well, please show a working example so we know what package you have used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `adjustbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,cfbox=blue 1pt 1pt]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to use `cfbox`? This is from manual (of `adjustbox`):

[image]

With `export` option these keys become available to `\includegraphics`

Comment: Using \includegraphics[width=2cm,cframe=blue]{example-image-a} works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The white gap between the image and frame can be changed by modifying the length `\fboxsep`, which defaults to 3pt.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{cyan}{\fboxrule=4pt\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-A}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \tcbincludegraphics[hbox,colframe=blue,boxrule=3pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,graphics options={width=3cm}]{example-image}
  \tcbincludegraphics[size=fbox,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!20!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop fuzzy shadow,title=my picture,colback=olive,boxsep=4pt,arc=0pt,graphics options={width=3cm}]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More in `tcolorbox` manual, page 213, section 10.1.